# Problem with negative step index in python

Tags: python, indexing, range, slice, negative-number

When we want to print reverse order of number using loops, for eg: 1 to 10 in reverse, we write the syntax as (10,0,-1), why don't we write it as (1,11,-1) ?
Doesn't -1 already mean reverse, so why do we write 10,0 instead of 1,11 for range?

Comment: How do you get from 1 to 10 when you reduce 1 every iteration? have a look at [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) signature and what the parameters are called.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for `range` in python are `range(start, stop, step)`.

The `start` value is the first index (inclusive) of the range function.  This defaults to 0.  In your case, the start value is 10.

The `stop` value is the last index (exclusive) of the range function.  This means that the index **before** this number will be the last number.

The `step` value is the change in index between each run.  This defaults to `1`, but in your case is `-1`.

This means that the order of execution in your example would be:

```
10 -> Start
9  -> Step (-1)
8  -> Step (-1)
7  -> Step (-1)
6  -> Step (-1)
5  -> Step (-1)
4  -> Step (-1)
3  -> Step (-1)
2  -> Step (-1)
1  -> Step (-1), Stop as next index would be 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Python reads your loop from the first argument until the last one. When you call:

```
for _ in range(10, 0, -1):
```

Python reads exactly like that:

1. What element I`m going from?
2. What element I`m going to?
3. What is the step I`m going with?

Otherwise, your loop won`t do anything.